I want the calendar min to be equal to the previous list item
I have a radzen calendar picker and i want the min date for it to be equal to the previous list items "GjelderFra", when debugging it apears that the index is 0 when trying to console.writeline() inside the code, but when doing a console.writeline inside the scope at the bottom the values are correct
@if(Form?.Kontonummer != null && Form.NyRente != null)
{
    int index = 0;
    Renteendring lastItem = null;
    <RadzenFieldset Text="Bestilling">
        <RadzenStack Gap="16">
            @foreach (var i in Form.NyRente)
            {

                <RadzenRow Gap="16">
                    <RadzenStack Gap="0" Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                        <!-- Gjelder fra dato -->
                        <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Overline">Gjelder fra</RadzenText>
                        <RadzenDatePicker Min="@(index > 0 ? Form.NyRente[index-1].GjelderFra : DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))" DateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" @bind-Value="i.GjelderFra" />
                    </RadzenStack>
                    <RadzenStack Gap="0" Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
                        <!-- Ny rentesats -->
                        <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Overline">Ny rente</RadzenText>
                        <RadzenNumeric Step="0.05" Format="0.00" TValue="double" AllowClear="true" Placeholder="Select something" @bind-Value="i.NyRente" Name="NyRente"></RadzenNumeric>
                    </RadzenStack>

                    <RadzenStack JustifyContent="JustifyContent.End" Gap="0">
                        <RadzenStack Gap="0.5rem" Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
                            @if (index > 0)
                            {
                                <RadzenButton Click="@(e => {Form.NyRente.Remove(i);})" Icon="cancel" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" />
                            }
                            @if (index == Form.NyRente.Count - 1 && Form.NyRente.Count < 4)
                            {
                                <RadzenButton Click="@(e => {Form.NyRente.Add(new Renteendring()); })" Icon="add_circle_outline" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" />
                            }
                            @{
                                index += 1;
                                
                                lastItem = i;

                            }
                        </RadzenStack>
                    </RadzenStack>
                </RadzenRow>

            }

tried both foreach loop and for loop without success
